# What are some books on Condensed Matter Physics like Horatiu Nastase's String Theory for Condensed Matter Physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, ads-cft

Are there more books and review papers on the applications of string theory methods like AdS/CFT on condensed matter systems like the one by Horatiu Nastase?
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/string-theory-methods-for-condensed-matter-physics/F9D08031D2147BD474C35ACBF97E6A28

Comment: Like this one: https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262038430/

Comment: Link to abstract page of the one by Horatiu Nastase?

Comment: Link to Horatiu Nastase's book : https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/string-theory-methods-for-condensed-matter-physics/F9D08031D2147BD474C35ACBF97E6A28